# Can't make my xinitrc be read in any way!

Tags: x11, startx

TLDR; I haven't being able to make `~/.xinitrc` being read at any moment. Not even if i edit `/etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc`.

I used to have i3wm so i really didn't use `~/.xinitrc` at all i just made programs ran editing i3's config file.
I tried editing my `~/.xinitrc` but the file just wasn't being read.
Now i uninstalled i3wm hoping to use dwm but after executing dwm from my xinitrc file it just wasn't working, whenever i execute `startx` i just get my terminal (urxvt) displayed awefully, even though i executed dwm from the xinitrc.
Now i workaround this issue with this command `startx /usr/local/bin/dwm` which works well.
I also noticed that i didn't have `.xsession` file i think i deleted all .x files when i was using i3wm.

Any ideas how can i get my xinitrc file to be read when starting X?

Thanks for reading.

This is my xinitrc file.

```
#!/bin/sh

# /etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc
#
# global xinitrc file, used by all X sessions started by xinit (startx)

# invoke global X session script
. /etc/X11/Xsession

sct 2000 &
setxkbmap us &

exec dwm
```

Comment: I don't know dwm. But… are you sure you need that ". /etc/X11/Xsession" line ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wouldn't override the default *xinitrc*, but instead provide a `~/.Xsession` file; the system default *xinitrc* will call that for the session, and perform a few cleanups when that returns after the end of the session.

The way you've built it, you run the normal Xsession, then after the session ends, perform your session setup and start dwm (which might fail at this point if the normal cleanup removes something you need).